# How to throw unauthorized exception?

Tags: java, security

Here is my code:

```
@RolesAllowed("admin")
@Path("/details/{id}")
@GET
@Consumes(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getDetails(@PathParam("id") String id) throws IOException
{
    String res = "";
    String targetURL = "http://www.api.com/?apikey=05&i=" + id;
    try{
        res = buildJSONString(targetURL);
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return res;
}
```

When I try to access to this api with user who have role admin a get good response but when Im trying to access with user who doesn't have role admin I get error 404 not found. How to handle this to return 401 error ?

Comment: Looks like there is really not found exception happens. Could you please post some logs from your web server, when you send the request in debug mode if possible?

Comment: I resolve this With deleting annotation @RolesAllowed("admin) and inside method from SecurityContext Im checking client role and throw my own exception if it is not admin.